# How to print out every other element from String in Kotlin?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement, kotlin

This is my code:

```
fun main(args:Array<String>) {

val message = "AL:OK:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:YY~~TYPE:3~~FOF:v1.0~~RSSI:-68~~PORT:8215~~TEMP:34.22~~CH1:OK~~CH2:KS~~CH3:PR~~CH4:VL~~CH5:KS~~CH6:OK~~AUX1:OK~~AUX2:KS~~AUX3:OK"

val messagetext: String = message.replace("AL:", "")
val sve = messagetext.split("~~")

var drugi = 0

for (par in sve) {
    if () {

        println(par)
        
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that in this `if()` statement: I need to write a code, that has to print out every second element from this string (message).

Even if I get a longer String in a message or in another order, code still needs to print out every second element.

In this case this should be the output:

```
TYPE:3
RSSI:-68
TEMP:34.22
CH2:KS
CH4:VL
CH6:OK
AUX2:KS
```

How can I achieve this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

This one-liner is better:

```
sve.forEachIndexed { i, v -> if (i%2==1) println(v) }
```

### old answer below

You can use the [filterIndexed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-indexed.html) function.

Replace your `for` loop together with the `if` inside with this:

```
sve.filterIndexed { index, _ -> index % 2 == 1 }.forEach{println(it)}
```

Comment: This is very fun approach! and it works pretty well. Thank you.
Can I ask you another question regarding this? 
Is it possible to adjust that code so it prints out "odd" next to every first element and "even" next to every second element?

Comment: @SlowLearner you are welcome. I'm not sure if I understood you right, but give this a try: `sve.forEachIndexed { i, v -> println("${if (i % 2 == 0) "even " else "odd "}$v") }`

Comment: Yes you understood it perfectly. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin has very verbose for loops. We can do something like this:

```
for (i in 1 until sve.size step 2) {
    println(sve[i])
}
```